# How does one segue from a UISearchBar to another ViewController with the entered text in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, uisearchbar

// I've seen this fucntion frequently in search for an answer. I wish I could control drag the UI element in the storyboard and create a segue this way but it does not work. I do not know how to do this programmatically.

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)

//I know I will also need

func prepare(for segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sener: Any?)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing [performSegue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue).

When you are ready to segue to the other viewController, for example in searchBarSearchButtonClicked, you just call performSegue with the identifier you set on the segue in the storyboard. The segue can be created by ctrl+dragging from the viewController that contains the searchBar to the next viewController. Then tap on the segue and give it an identifier.

Inside prepareForSegue, which will be invoked by the system as a result of your call to performSegue, you can get access to the next viewController through the segue.destination property. If you declare a variable for the search string on the second viewController, you can set it like this:

```
(segue.destination as? SecondViewController).searchText = searchText
```

Comment: Yes, but I cannot control drag the UISearchBar to the other ViewController and thus cannot create a segue with a specific identifier. When I try to control drag to the other controller no interface pops up to give me an option of what kind of segue I want namely show. I can do this with buttons but not labels or the UISearchBar. Thank you so much for responding too.

Comment: I tried control dragging from the top of the ViewController in the storyboard where it shows what class it is and says exit. This worked. Control dragging directly from the UISearchBar was futile for me. Normally I work with android and have found the intent system much easier. Thank you for your help!